# Singular support of an irreducible perverse sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

I was studying Sheaves on Manifolds by Kashiwara and Schapira, and while the singular support seems like a complicated invariant I cannot seem to find a counterexample to the following:

Let $X$ be a smooth complex variety and $\mathcal{F}=IC(U,\mathcal{L})$ be an irreducible perverse sheaf, where $\mathcal{L}$ is a local system on $U\subset X$. Then $SS(\mathcal{F})=T_{\overline{U}}^*X$, where the latter means the conormal bundle at $\overline{U}$.

This seems too easy of an answer to be true, but I still cannot find either a counterexample or a proof, and I cannot think of how to get an explicit answer using the Riemann-Hilbert correspondance either. Any help?

Comment: What is your definition of support of a perverse sheaf? Union of support of cohomology $\mathcal{H}^*({\mathcal{F}})$? Also, are you looking for the singular support for $\mathcal{D}$-modules, which is really a subvariety of the cotangent bundle.

Comment: Not support, singular support. The singular support is defined on the level of constructible sheaves (see Kashiwara-Schapira, "Sheaves on Manifolds") and it is a subvariety of the cotangent bundle. For perverse sheaves it agrees with the singular support for D-modules under the Riemann-Hilbert corrrespondance. I guess an equivalent question is: Is the singular support for an irreducible $D$-module just the conormal bundle to its support?

Comment: No, consider structure sheaf as a $\mathcal{D}$-module on a smooth variety $X$, it's singular support is zero section of conormal bundle. Also, Riemann-Hilbert correspondece is for those $\mathcal{D}$-modules that are holonomic and has regular singularity. Holonomic means that the dimension of the singular support is $n=\dim X$.

Comment: Well the zero section of the cotangent bundle has nothing that is conormal to it so it satisfies the pproposition right? Also yes I meant the holonomic $D$-modules with regular singularities, my bad.

Comment: But the conormal bundle to X is indeed the zero section, isn't it?

Comment: Now asked on MathOverflow: [Singular support of an irreducible perverse sheaf](https://mathoverflow.net/q/360492)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody else reading this, know that this was just answered in MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/360492/singular-support-of-an-irreducible-perverse-sheaf

Comment: If you ask "Is the singular support for an irreducible $\mathcal{D}$-module always contained in the zero section of conormal bundle?". That will make everyone happy.

Comment: No @AGlearner that is not what I am asking. So Let $X$ be a smooth variety and $Y$ a closed subvariety. The conormal to $Y$ bundle is the subbundle of the cotangent bundle that is supported on $Y$ and is dual to $TY$. Does that make sense? For example, for the affine plane the conormal bundle to the $x$-axis is the subvariety of the cotangent bundle of covectors $(x,0,0,\lambda dy)$.

Comment: In particular, "conormal bundle"$\neq$"cotangent bundle"

Comment: Ah, I see. Somehow I was thinking about "cotangent bundle" when I read and write "conormal bundle". Sorry about the confusion (and I'll delete the irrelavant comments).